# Disable pinch zoom in MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I want to disable pinch zoom at `barchart` in `MPAndroidChart` library how i can do that.

```
library.barchart.setpinzoomenable(false);
```

also not working.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try this,

> Disable all zooming:

```
chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
```

More info refer [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/458)

Comment: Disable Y-Zoom: mChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
Disable X-Zoom: mChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);

Answer (score 3):

Marker will continue to work but zoom will be disable

```
chart.setTouchEnabled(true)
chart.setPinchZoom(false)
chart.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
```

Comment: To disable double tap to zoom, write  chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

Answer (score 2):

```
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    fragmentHomeBinding.lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
```

In above code, I have enabled scaling in X-axis and disabled in Y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
  library.barchart.setPinchZoom(false);
```

Comment: this doesn't disable vertical and horizontal zoom

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has included anything about axis wise scaling after turning off zooming (as per the latest library), the following lines will disable pinch to zoom as well as x,y-scaling whatsoever:

```
barChart.setPinchZoom(false)
barChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
```